# Play Framework: couldn't write meta-data in eclipse project

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have created a new play project called 'first app'. I then went to the project dir in terminal and used the command "play eclipse". It said that it was successful. I then imported the project into eclipse. This worked, but it gave a warning that '*Periodic workspace save has encountered a problem: it couldn't write meta-data for /RemoteSystemsTempFiles*'. **Will this be an issue?**  If so, what should I do about it?

On a side note, in the project directory, there are also a lot of resources sitting around. Is this normal for an eclipsified play project?

Comment: Are you importing it as an "Existing Project into Workspace" or as "File System"?

Comment: an "Existing Project"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
~/tmp$ play new first-app
~/tmp$ cd first-app/
~/tmp/first-app$ play eclipse
~/tmp/first-app$ ls -al
```

That's what I get:

```
drwxrwxr-x 10 me me  4096 Jun 20 11:17 .
drwxrwxr-x  5 me me 57344 Jun 20 11:16 ..
drwxrwxr-x  4 me me  4096 Jun 20 11:16 app
-rw-rw-r--  1 me me 16630 Jun 20 11:17 .classpath
drwxrwxr-x  2 me me  4096 Jun 20 11:16 conf
-rw-rw-r--  1 me me   141 Apr  2  2013 .gitignore
drwxrwxr-x  4 me me  4096 Jun 20 11:16 project
-rw-rw-r--  1 me me   265 Jun 20 11:17 .project
drwxrwxr-x  5 me me  4096 Jun 20 11:16 public
-rw-rw-r--  1 me me   151 Apr  2  2013 README
drwxrwxr-x  2 me me  4096 Jun 20 11:17 .settings
drwxrwxr-x  5 me me  4096 Jun 20 11:17 target
drwxrwxr-x  4 me me  4096 Jun 20 11:17 .target
drwxrwxr-x  2 me me  4096 Jun 20 11:16 test
```

And I can import it into eclipse without any problem.

Comment: I get the same but with '.DS_Store'and 'build.sbt'. Does the build.sbt mean it was not eclipsified successfully. I can still use eclipse with it would seem but the error still appears.

Comment: what version of play are you using. I am using 2.2. Will that have an effect?

Comment: I have fixed it. Thanks. I just eclipsified it again with a new project and there was no .DS_Store. Now it works and I have completed the tutorial. I am not sure why this made a difference. Any ideas?